# Checking/Unchecking a None Checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have a group of checkboxes. One is conditions[]. The last checkbox for this array is named "none". That way if the user selects this checkbox all of the other checkboxes should be checked.

I'm trying to figure out how how to write my if statement so that when the page is loaded and any of the other checkboxes are checked then it needs to make sure that the none is not checked. Vice versa if none of the other checkboxes are checked then I need to make sure that the one that is none is checked.

Keep in mind that these are dynamically created with none actually being in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear.

```
// you need to add a class('.otherCheckboxClass') to all the checkbox other than the none one.

var allOtherChecked = true;
// go trough all checkboxes other than the none one
$( ".otherCheckboxClass" ).each(function() {
  // verify if one of them is not checked
  if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
     // if one is checked, set var to false  
     allOtherChecked = false;
  }

   // if all of them are checked, add check to the none checkbox.
   if(allOtherChecked == true){
     $('.noneCheckBox').prop( "checked", true );
   }

});
```